# Implementing an ActionListener to a JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

in my code I used ActionListener before for an JButton.
I tried to enhance my program with some menubars I learned.
So, I tired to implement an ActionListener to my JButtonItem but it won't respond. Whatever I write it does not respond, just the error I get.

I want that my JButtonItem versItem use an ActionListener to open e.g. an system.out.print or an new text field.

```
*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package yttut;

// Einbindung der Bibs

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
/**
 *
 * @author tom
 */
public class GuiTaschenrechner extends JFrame implements ActionListener { // Klasse benutzt JFrame
    
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu fileMenu;
    JMenu testMenu;
    JMenuItem versItem;
    
    JLabel labelOperand1; //Schildchen
    JLabel labelOperand2;
    JLabel labelOperator;
    
    JTextField fieldOperand1; // Normale Textfelder 
    JTextField fieldOperand2;
    
    JButton buttonRechnen; // Normaler Button
    
    String operator; // Normale Zuweisung
    public GuiTaschenrechner(String titel, String operator){
     
    this.operator = operator;    
       
    setTitle(titel); // Titel des Fensters
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Was passiert wenn man das Fenster schließt
    
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // Ordnet die Komponten auf dem Interface
    
    setSize(350,150); // Größe des Fensters
    setResizable(true); // Ob der Benutzer das Fenster vergrößern kann
    
    
     
    
    initComponents(); // Methodenaufruf
    
    // WICHTIG!: Nach dem Methodenaufruf machen
    
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(testMenu);
    testMenu.add(versItem);
   
    add(labelOperand1); //Aufruf der einzelnen Komponenten
    add(labelOperand2);
    add(fieldOperand1);
    add(labelOperator);
    add(fieldOperand2);
    add(buttonRechnen);
    
    setVisible(true); // Fenster wird sichtbar gemacht
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Wo das Fenster gespawnt wird
    
    
    
    }
    
    private void initComponents(){
        
    
     
    
    labelOperand1 = new JLabel("1.Summand"); //Was auf dem Label stehen soll
    labelOperand2 = new JLabel("2.Summand");  
    labelOperator = new JLabel(operator);
    
    fieldOperand1 = new JTextField(8); // Wie groß das Textfield sein soll
    fieldOperand2 = new JTextField(8);
    
    
    buttonRechnen = new JButton("Rechen!"); // Was auf dem Button stehen soll
    buttonRechnen.addActionListener(this); // Hört dem Button zu
    
    
    
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    
    setJMenuBar( menuBar);
    
    fileMenu = new JMenu("Datei");
    testMenu = new JMenu("Testing...");
    fileMenu.addActionListener(this);
    versItem = new JMenuItem("Versionsansicht");
    versItem.addActionListener(this);
    
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param e
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //Override aus implements ActionListener
        
        
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(fieldOperand1.getText()); // get Text gibt String daher umwandlung nach int
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(fieldOperand2.getText());
        
        int ergebnis;
        
        if(e.getSource().equals(versItem)){
            
            System.out.println("Dsa");
        }
        
         if(e.getSource()==fileMenu){
            
            System.out.println("Dsa");
        }
        
        
        
        if(operator.equals("+")){
            ergebnis = op1 + op2;
            
        }else if(operator.equals("-")){
            ergebnis = op1 - op2;
            
        }else if(operator.equals("*")){
            ergebnis = op1 * op2;
            
        }else if(operator.equals("/")){
            ergebnis = op1 / op2;
            
        }else{
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            ergebnis = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    
        // Ergbnisausgabe in einer Dialogbox
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ergebnis: " + ergebnis,"BERECHNET",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         
         fieldOperand1.setText(""); // Nach Ergebnisausgabe werden hier die Felder wieder leer gemaacht
         fieldOperand2.setText("");
            
                 }
        
    }
```

Comment: What is a `JButtonItem`?. Use the proper class name so we don't have to guess what you are talking about.  *just the error I get.* - what error? Post the error text as part of the question. Note a JMenu does not respond to an ActionEvent, so you should not add an ActionListener to your fileMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is:

When the `menuItem` is pressed, do something (`System.out.println`) like printing (`"Dsa"`) and when the button is pressed, do somethign else (the calculations).

> Whatever I write it does not respond, just the error I get.

But you were getting an error and `Dsa` printed at the very bottom

And I think the error you were getting was something like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
```

And if you scrolled to the bottom of the error you'd find `Dsa` on your console.

The error above means you didn't write something into the fields, and because you were executing the calculations every time you entered the `ActionListener` this was happening because the text fields were empty.

You were on the right track with this:

```
if(e.getSource().equals(versItem)){
        
    System.out.println("Dsa");
}
    
if(e.getSource()==fileMenu){
        
    System.out.println("Dsa");
}
```

However you were asking for the `fileMenu` and `versItem` but never for your button, and actually the `fileMenu` one isn't really needed, so you could change things this way:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { // Override aus implements ActionListener
    if (e.getSource().equals(versItem)) {
        System.out.println("Dsa");
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(buttonRechnen)) {
        doOperation();
    }
}
```

Where you move all the logic of the operations out of that method, this way it's easier to understand what's happening.

And your `doOperation` method could look like this with some improvements with a `switch` instead (You could move the operations to an `enum` if you wanted to):

```
private void doOperation() {
    int ergebnis = 0;
    int op1 = Integer.parseInt(fieldOperand1.getText()); // get Text gibt String daher umwandlung nach int
    int op2 = Integer.parseInt(fieldOperand2.getText());
    
    switch(operator) {
    case "+":
        ergebnis = op1 + op2;
        break;
    case "-":
        ergebnis = op1 - op2;
        break;
    case "*":
        ergebnis = op1 * op2;
        break;
    case "/":
        ergebnis = op1 / op2;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        break;
    }
    // Ergbnisausgabe in einer Dialogbox
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ergebnis: " + ergebnis, "BERECHNET", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    fieldOperand1.setText(""); // Nach Ergebnisausgabe werden hier die Felder wieder leer gemaacht
    fieldOperand2.setText("");
}
```

Now everytime you click on the `versItem` you'll print `Dsa` to the console and continue doing your operations when pressing the button.

If this wasn't your problem, let me know so that I can edit and improve the answer accordingly

Comment: That was because you were always executing the calculations part, it's easier to see if you move that code outside and can focus on those parts, glad to help you :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I couldn't print Dsa out whiteout putting numbers in the textfields of fieldOperand1 and fieldOperand2. And the error I got was the same one as you written in your answer above. Thanks for your effort you solved it perfectly.

Comment: Next time if you have an error, add it into your question, this could be of help for others and you'll get more, faster and better answers :)

Comment: Yes, my bad. The next time I will definitely do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```